# How to change the don't-escape HTML delimiter in Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, mustache

I know I can change the default delimiter using `Mustache.tags('[[', ']]');`

I dig into the source code, but I can't find and figure out how to change the don't-escape HTML delimiter, which is `{{{ }}}` by default. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you mean that mustache should not escape HTML by default? [The code I've checked out](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) doesn't provide anything like that. You'd have to implement it.

Comment: Yes, "All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}." Source http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What are you trying to tell me with that? And I'm still not sure what you are asking for. Changing the default behaviour regarding escaping HTML, or changing the delimiter `{{{` and `}}}`. later is not that simple, because it's hardcoded into the parser and defined as `openingTag + "{"` and `"}" + closingTag`. And with hardcoded I mean, that you'd possibly have to change logic, not just a (few) regex

Comment: My question still stands like the title, change the don't-escape HTML delimiter, which is `{{{ }}}` by default. Sorry to waste your time and makes you go through the source code. This part is a low priority in my project, so asking here is better (maybe someone had experience to change the delimiter) rather than understanding the source to save my time.

Comment: Yeah, btw the question description is not a good English, I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the `don't-escape` HTML delimiter is only possible by modifying the source because it's hardcoded into the parser and defined as `openingTag + "{" and "}" + closingTag`.

And by hardcoded I mean that you'd possibly have to change logic, not just a (few) regex. Thanks to @Thomas for dedicating his time to me.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your question is how to turn off the default html entity escaping behaviour of a mustache template when you have specified custom delimiters. This can be a bit confusing since the default behaviour, that you will see if you look this up, is to use triple braces such as `{{{some-value}}}`. I'm going to assume you mean from a users point of view and not a developers point of view - despite the reference to the source code.

There are two ways:

1. Mustache provides an alternative syntax for turning off HTML escaping using the `&` character. So with your custom delimiters of '[[' and ']]' you would specify your placeholder as

   ```
    [[&some-value]]
   ```
2. Simply use '{ }' within your custom delimiters. E.g.

   ```
    [[{some-value}]]
   ```

I don't believe there is any way to change either of these inner syntaxes. Some templating systems are a lot more flexible (e.g. doT uses regexes for all matching), but mustache is less flexible (which many will see as an advantage)

Hope that clears things up. I know this is an old question, but perhaps this might still
help you or anyone else also looking this up.